# Скрипт для Windows

Tags: windows

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажимании какой-либо клавиши открывался конкретный файл на компе?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не соответствует нормам сайта: вы не представили контекста вопроса (нет технологии, на которой основывалось бы решение, нет языка для реализации, ...), нет попыток решения проблемы с вашей стороны, себя тоже лучше не оскорблять, название не соответствует телу вопроса, ответы на данный вопрос не несут какого-либо смысла, т. к. ваш вопрос имеет слишком широко поставленную проблему и каждый участник сможет интерпретировать её по разному.

Comment: Моё мнение: для таких баринов как вы есть опция закрытия вопросов.

Comment: [Справка по задаванию вопросов на SO (Stack Overflow, этот сайт)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать "Быстрый вызов" из ярлыка на любой файл. Главное чтоб это был "Ярлык")
А скрипт, смотря на каком языке) там нужно ещё отслеживать событие нажатия клавищ)

Answer (score 1):

- Создаете к файлу ярлык.
- На ярлыке щелкаете правой клавишей, выбираете "Свойства".
- В "свойствах" есть поле "Быстрый вызов".
- Ставите курсор на белом поле справа от слов "Быстрый вызов".
- Нажимаете сочетание клавиш. Например, `Alt + Shift + 0`.
- Теперь, кода вы нажмете `Alt + Shift + 0`, ваш файл откроется.